# Display Loading Screen and Hide It After Formatting of Data

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

My application calls API that returns list of data that will be displayed in tabular format. It will be place in a partial view.

i want to display a loading screen when the page load and hide it after the formatting of table.
How would I achieve this? i know i should use jquery but that's all i know,

Here's my Code for displaying.

```
<table>

<tr>
   @{ 
       var count = typeof(ModelType).GetProperties().Count() - 1;
       for (int i = count; i != 0; i--)
       {
        <th></th>
       }
     }
<tr>
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Phone)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.LastName)
            </td>
        </tr>                    
    }     

</table>
```

### Edit

I want to display the blockUI until after the formatting of tabular data.

my JS using BlockUI.

```
function LoadPartialFile()
{
    $('#blocker').block({ message: null });

    $.ajax({
        cache: false,
        url: '/User/GetFilePartialTable',
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'html',
        contentType: 'application/html; charset=utf-8',
        success: function (viewHTML) {
            $('#replaced').html(viewHTML);
            },
        error: function (request, status, err) {
            alert(status);
            alert(err);
        }
    });
    $('#blocker').unblock();
}
```

my view

```
<div><button onclick="LoadPartialFile()">Load Chart</button> 
<button onclick="LoadPartialFile()">Load Chart</button> 
</div>
<div id="blocker">        
    <div id="replaced" style="height:500px;width:100%">          
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You got to check JQuery BlockUI - http://malsup.com/jquery/block/

Comment: @ramiramilu hi rami, i tried using the blockUI before calling the ajax request. I want to display it until it finished formatting, but it's not working.

See my Edit

Answer (score 2):

Example with jQuery BlockUI Plugin. HTH

1/ [Download](http://malsup.github.io/jquery.blockUI.js) and include `jquery.blockUI.js` into your asp.net mvc project.

### [image]

2/ Include the `jquery.blockUI.js` to `BundleConfig`.

```
public class BundleConfig
{
    public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
    {
        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js",
                    "~/Scripts/jquery.blockUI.js"));
    }
}
```

3/ Check `_Layout.cshtml` if the bundles are rendered

```
<body>
    @RenderBody()

    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
</body>
```

4/ In the view call `$.blockUI()` at the ajax start and `$.unblockUI()` when ajax call finishes.

```
<div>
    <button onclick="LoadPartialFile()">Load Chart</button>
</div>

<div id="replaced" style="height:500px;width:100%"></div>

@section Scripts {
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function LoadPartialFile() {

            $.blockUI({
                css: {
                    border: 'none',
                    padding: '15px',
                    backgroundColor: '#000',
                    '-webkit-border-radius': '10px',
                    '-moz-border-radius': '10px',
                    opacity: .5,
                    color: '#fff'
                }
            });

            $.ajax({
                cache: false,
                url: "@Url.Action("ListOfData", "BlockingUi")",
                type: 'GET',
                dataType: 'html',
                contentType: 'application/html; charset=utf-8'
            })
            .done(function(viewHtml) {
                $('#replaced').html(viewHtml);
            })
            .fail(function(request, status, err) {
                alert(status);
                alert(err);
            })
            .always(function() {
                $.unblockUI();
            });
        }
    </script>
}
```

5/ Add Controller with action which returns partial view

```
public class BlockingUiController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult ListOfData()
    {
        Thread.Sleep(2500); // For testing of the blocking UI
        var model = new List<ListOfDataModel>
        {
            new ListOfDataModel
            {
                Name = "John", 
                LastName = "Doe", 
                Phone = "111-222-333"
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: The same solution I need it in Form submit..Does anyone help?